# Page number UI on Pagination on AngularJS Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I have configured this module on AngularJS [angular-datatables](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withAjax) and i have found out that there is a UI error when i try to hover on the page number on the lower right side of the table.. see pic

[image]

As you can see, when i try to hover on page 25, there is this grey square that will appear as i try to move to the next number (26) it will also move.

I have followed the file inclusion on the site. are there any files that i need to include? it does not state on the site that there are files i need to include other than what is being mentioned.

**Added Inpect Detail:**

[image]

Comment: i didn't see any thing in demo. inspect it and see what is it?

Comment: yes that what i think also, i did not see any gray sqaures on the demo.. see my updated post for the inspect

Comment: can you post orginal link demo?

Comment: this is what i followed http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withAjax by the way the pagination style is way different from what is on the demo.. and i have not configure any style at all

Comment: may be override 'paginate_button.active' class.

Comment: hmm i didnt quite got you there.. what do you mean?

Comment: A link that you send have gray style while the image, nothing else!!!! and also don't display any gray sqaures on the demo.try to change css style.

Comment: when i inspect selected button that display <a class="paginate_button current"> .... may be you should use last version.